# Is it possible to decouple the location of the active vs. archived log files with apache log4cxx?

Tags: apache, logging, log4cxx

Also, is it possible to configure a size based rolling file appender to do auto compression like a rolling file appender?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to decouple the location of the active vs. archived log files with apache log4cxx?

Not out of the box, but you can achieve it by writing a new appender, overridding the `RollingFileAppender`. Override the `setOption()` method to provide a new option denoting a logging directory, say `loggingDir`, and the `setFile()` method to take this new option into account.

As for zipping the rolled-over file, I'm only sure that a good extension point to implement it in would be the

```cpp
virtual void append(const spi::LoggingEventPtr& event, log4cxx::helpers::Pool& p);
```

method; however, I'm not a C++ guy, so I don't know what's best to use to implement the compression.